# Voices too loud in Tropico 4

Tags: tropico-4

When you click on a person to see details the voice is too loud. It seems that the "Voice Volume" control is not working for me, the voices end up being controlled by the "Sound Effects Volume".

Comment: Why don't you turn down the sound effects volume?

Comment: @Caleb Because I like the other sound effects, so I was wondering if there is any way to control only the sound of the voices.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft It's a great game actually ;)

Comment: How is it only $0.39?

Comment: @mafutrct http://www.reddit.com/r/Steam/comments/2dqe5e/tropico_4_collectors_bundle_39_cents/

Comment: I missed that, a shame!